# Is deleting an element in the middle of a std::vector still expensive with movable types?

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, move-semantics

It is generally thought of deleting an element in the middle of a `std::vector` to be costly, as it needs to copy every element after it down to fill the hole.

With C++11, `std::vector` will instead *move* all the elements down, which should be very fast (if only in relation to the copy), atleast I think so. It will still be linear in time, sure, but in general it should be faster than the old version.

Will this be true? Do I not have to worry about deleting some object in the middle anymore?

Comment: Couldn't the objects be swapped in C++03 anyway? If so, the performance difference would be pretty minimal.'

Comment: @jalf: Well, that's how the `unafe_erase` works - `swap` with last and `pop_back`, but if you want to keep the order, you can't just swap.

Comment: @Xeo: In the same way that you would remove from the middle and then *move* by one the elements to the end of the vector, you can *swap* the element to remove with the next element, *moving* it to the end of the vector and then calling `pop_back`.

Comment: @jalf: As far as I know, only VC9 performs "swaptimization" in their STL, as it's not required for containers to hold efficiently swappable elements.

Comment: @David: it seems that in your reply to @Xeo you're describing a more complex and arbitrary way to achieve the same?

Comment: @Alf, I am not fully understanding your question, but the intent of the comment is that it depends. With types that are not *swappable* nor *movable* there will be no difference. With types that are *swappable* it will depend on the implementation of the STL. As to the particular comment, it deals with the fact that not only `unsafe_erase` can be optimized with swaps, but other operations can. That is, `swap` can be used to provide poor-man's *move* implementation

Comment: Being extremely unsatisfied with the "swap algorithm" was one of my chief motivations for standardizing move semantics.  The "swap algorithm" actually slows things down for the common case that the element type is a scalar (e.g. `vector<int>`).  Naturally you can specialize for scalars and avoid the performance hit.  But you'll probably hit it eventually.  For example doing the swap algorithm for `vector<complex<double>>` will get hit.

Comment: @Howard Hinnant: I thought that in VC9, they only "swaptimized" certain Standard types, and then in VC9 SP1 only UDTs that could have a special tag requesting it.

Comment: I have no access or knowledge of VC products.  I was speaking on a more general level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you take into account what the standard uses for cost, it will be exactly as costly. The standard states the costs in terms of operations performed on the contained type, and that number of operations is still the same, it is just that each one of them will be faster.

As an example, consider in C++03 the cost of inserting an element in the middle of a `vector<string>`. The standard calls that `O(N)`, where `N` is the size of the vector, but the actual cost is `O(N * M)` where `M` is the size of the strings. The reason for ignoring the `M` when analyzing the cost of operations in the containers is that it depends on the contained element. That cost in C++0x with a movable type will be `O(N)` (strings can be moved to the new positions), but the advertised complexity will be `O(N)` in both cases.

For a simple counter-example, if you consider that insertion in the middle of a vector is an expensive operation in C++03, and you consider `std::vector<int>`, then insertion in the middle of a vector in C++0x is just as expensive, there is no speedup in that case.

Also note, that any potential improvement would depend on your objects being *movable* (which they don't need to be), and that some of the current STL implementations are already optimized in a similar way (without language support), for example, Dinkumware implementation (I think it was this one) have some optimizations by which when a `std::vector<std::vector<T> >` grows, it creates the new storage and initializes with *empty* vectors (that have no allocated memory so the cost is minimal) and then `swap`s the vectors in the old and new allocated regions, effectively implementing *move* semantics.

Comment: strings will not be faster moved (than copied) if they all contain less than 16 characters. because the are stored inplace.

Answer (score 15):

It depends on what's in the vector. If it's a POD or pointer I can't imagine that it would make any difference. If it's class instances that are heavy to copy, but can be moved very fast I'd expect a speedup with C++0x.

However, I think that if deleting elements from the middle of std::vectors is a bottleneck in your code, C++0x is probably not the right fix. Consider datastructures that handles such cases better instead, or `std::iter_swap` plus `std::vector::pop_back` if the order of the elements doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6):

Effectively, in the vast majority of cases, it will be significantly faster to move than to copy. Any type which has information stored by reference which would otherwise have to be copied can prevent the copy- so, for example, pretty much all containers, smart pointers, etc, and any class involving those types.

Of course this is still linear time, so if you have a million ints, it won't go any faster. However, moving things like containers and smart pointers can be several orders of magnitude faster than copying them.

Comment: for the smart pointer you must surely be talking of `shared_ptr` because `unique` is not copiable so it can't be compared to moving. In the `shared` case the only potential speed-up, is the skipping of ref count atomic add and decr, and a comparison as well. but you can't avoid the copy of 2 pointers. (ref cnt object and pointee)

Answer (score 5):

I'm still a newbie to C++0x's move stuff, but I can't really see how you'll get any useful speedups here that are inherent to `vector`.

It must all come down to your element type: *I can't imagine that you'll get any speedup unless objects of your element type are faster to move than to copy*.

Comment: That's basically true for nearly every expensive type.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yes, but the OP didn't specify whether his element type is expensive or not.

Comment: If it's not expensive, then deleting from the middle is not expensive and this is premature optimization anyway.

Comment: @DeadMG: If the vector is large, then deleting from the middle will be expensive even if copying/moving is cheap per-element.

Comment: @DeadMG: What's the premature optimisation here? The introduction of move semantics to C++?

Answer (score 1):

First point that, about to decide you need a vector or list? If you don't want index based access to the data structure, list would be good as your deletions are happening in the middle of the container. Also you have to consider other variants like trees to decide the best for you. This might not affect your performance much but still just for the sake of sharing information, there's a chance for the contents in the list to be spreaded across multiple page files and hence performance will be compromised on using large amount of data.

[Rvalue reference and move constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors) can improve the performance of containers. It can avoid several unencessary copying operations etc.